# Listing employees and their salary as percentage of total salaries using derived table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with names, job, salary etc.. what i want to do is to list all names, salary and a third column with their salary as a percentage of total salary, [like this](https://gyazo.com/179626fb821541405bce72b604cf9475).

The table looks [like this](https://gyazo.com/95562f6e7bf775aed80954608a2ac5e8).

I am new to mysql and any help is good help.

Thanks

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could compute the total salary in a subquery, and then CROSS JOIN that with the employee table to be able to do the computation, like :

```
SELECT
    emp.epname,
    emp.salary,
    emp.salary/tot.salary * 100
FROM 
    employees emp
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(salary) salary FROM employees 
    ) tot
```

With MySQL 8.0, window functions make it easier :

```
SELECT
    epname,
    salary,
    salary/(SUM(salary) OVER()) * 100
FROM employees
```